# Calculating Expected Value for Repeated Earnings

Tags: expected-value

I'm reading conflicting answers about expected value over multiple rounds.

I read this question [Two different books are giving two different solutions.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3746630/two-different-books-are-giving-two-different-solutions/3746638) , and it had this question

> Every day a trader either makes 50% with probability 0.6 or loses 50%
> with probability 0.4. What is the probability the trader will be ahead
> at the end of a year, 260 trading days? Over what number of days does
> the trader have the maximum probability of making money?

And someone in the comments calculated this as the expected value:

$(0.6⋅1.5+0.4⋅0.5)^{260}=1.1^{260}≈57,833,669,934.$

But then I go to the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kelly_criterion wikipedia page linked in this question and I see this problem:

> In a study, each participant was given $25 and asked to place
> even-money bets on a coin that would land heads 60% of the time.
> Participants had 30 minutes to play, so could place about 300 bets

And the page describes the expected value with the geometric mean returns (1.02034) not the arithmetic mean (1.04):
$10,505 = {\displaystyle 25\cdot (1.02034)^{300}}$

So which answer is correct, or are they both correct saying different things?